# Tag questions with or - shouldn't they be the opposite in the tag

Tags: grammar, idioms

I wonder why tag questions have a tag that is not the other possibility of the sentence that precedes the tag.

For instance:

1) "This tag question is an example, or is it?"

Shouldn't it be:

2) "This tag question is an example, or isn't it?

The negative sentence:

3) "This tag question is not an example, or is it?"

(2) and (3) sound more "logical" to me, and in both the tag is the negative of the sentence preceding the tag.

Comment: Elaborate? I dont know what you are asking.

Comment: This sounds like something for ELL.SE

Comment: @ rraallvv: Your question seems to be in danger of being closed as "Unclear". I assume your uncertainty here stems from reading such advice as [Positive statement ->question tag negative - *You are Tom, **aren't you?*** Negative statement->question tag positive - *He isn't Joe, **is he?*** If I'm right, perhaps you could edit your question to clarify that you're asking how this principle of "assertion/denial" reversal works for "tag questions" starting with ***or***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tried to clarify the doubt i had, thanks.

Comment: [Here's the "missing link"](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/qu_tags.htm) that should have been in my previous comment (implying question tags *always **reverse*** the original "statement"). And [here's a more comprehensive summary](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-questions-tag-special.htm) pointing out that there are various exceptions to that general principle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there's something slightly unusual about [tag questions](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/tagqueterm.htm) prefaced by ***or***...

> 1: ["It won't be soon, or will it?”](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22vasectomising%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#fp=81c90092a5db4935&q=%22or%20will%20it%20he%22&start=20&tbm=bks)
>    2: ["I'll be back later. Or will I?" she asked, looking at him.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TbFaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22or%20will%20I%20she%20asked%22&dq=%22or%20will%20I%20she%20asked%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tjoUUsXFIurH0QWPw4CQBQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw)

In #1 the tag presents the *opposite* possibility (perhaps it *will* be soon), which makes sense since after ***or*** we naturally expect something *different* as an alternative outcome.

But #2 simply echoes the original possibility. There's no doubt this is idiomatically perfectly normal (she'd be very unlikely to have said *"Or won't I?"* there).

I think the only way to understand this is to accept that the word ***or*** fundamentally changes the nature of a "tag question". Or perhaps it might be better to say such constructions aren't really tag questions at all in the normal sense.

In practice, what it boils down to is that ***or*** automatically implies the preceding statement ***might*** not be true, and it's just a matter of idiomatic choice/stylistic preference whether you follow it with the *same* or an *alternative* statement.

Thus, there's no "fixed rule" about whether the assertion/negation of the first statement should be *echoed* or *reversed* by the "tag question restatement". But taking particular note of example #2 above, I think idiomatically we normally present the restatement as an *assertion*, not a *negation*.

---

Having said that, there are many contexts where these two examples *without **or*** are equivalent...

> ["It is him, **is** it?"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22vasectomising%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#fp=81c90092a5db4935&q=%22it%20is%20him%20is%20it%22&tbm=bks)
>    ["It is him, **isn't** it?"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22vasectomising%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#fp=81c90092a5db4935&q=%22it%20is%20him%20isn%27t%20it%22&tbm=bks)

...so maybe ***or*** isn't so crucial here after all.

Comment: Well done for interpreting OP's question. Last night I guessed it was question tags myself, but you've covered the question of using positive or negative verbs with "or" far better than I ever could.